# Run PHP script when file from a certain directory are requested

Tags: php, caching

I have just written some PHP code to combine all the JS on my website into a single file, hash it, then echo out the `<script>` tag with the hashed filename as the source. I store all these hashed files in a single folder, and delete old hashes every time a new hash is generated.

I want to be able to turn on caching for this file, as the hashed filename determines when the browser needs to download a new file (IE: The actual URL that it requests is different). Does anyone know how to  hook into this request in PHP? Something like:

```
if ($_GET['folder'] = "path/to/hashed/folder/or/file")
{
    //Do something
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are serving your JavaScript with PHP, you can't hook into the request.  However, you don't need to set caching headers with PHP.  You can configure your web server to do this directly.  How you do this depends on what server you are using.

Answer (score 0):

What you are going to use for this is a file called .htaccess.  Here is a simple rule that sends everything through one file, here named index.php.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/some_file_that_you_want_to_exclude_from_this_rule
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/some_other_file_that_you_want_to_exclude_from_this_rule
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```

The full URL will be in $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], and other variables in $_SERVER will point you to other information ($_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'] excludes the host name).

Comment: There is no indication that Apache is the server in use.  Even if it was, there is often no need to use `.htaccess` files... they only slow things down if the directives you need could be placed in or included from the main config file.  And finally, there is nothing in the question indicating that all requests should be sent through PHP.  For simple caching directives, the web server itself is plenty capable of adding the appropriate headers.